# Как сделать, чтобы окно с подтверждением запуска из автозагрузки появлялось лишь один раз?

Tags: c#, windows

Написал самому себе тулзу, помогающую в нелегкой рутинной жизни с намеком на распространение хотя бы среди знакомых. Программа прописывает себя в автозагрузку вот этим кодом при первом запуске:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true); 
rkApp.SetValue("Indexing tool", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

И все бы хорошо, но при старте системы выдается окошко c подтверждением системы безопасности:

[image: *окно, которое надо убрать*]

Есть ли возможность выводить его только один раз, чтобы это разрешение надо было выдавать единожды?

У меня есть догадка, что можно попытаться инсталлировать приложение в Program files и тогда оно будет запускаться нормально, но это только догадка. Плюс как вариант, насколько я понимаю, если подписать .exe, то все будет нормально, но самоподписанные сертификаты, полагаю не прокатят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скриншоте видно, что вы запускаете приложение по сети. Это неправильно, потому что

- требует наличия сетевого устройства при каждой загрузке компьютера,
- файл на сетевой шаре легко подменить на вредоносный.

Скопируйте приложение локально.

Comment: Дело в том, что запускаю на виртуальной машине с мака, попробую прописать нормальный путь через диск C

Comment: Большое спасибо. Если прописать путь через диск С, то все работает.